# R and odbcDriverConnect() to connect R to teradata

Tags: r, odbc, teradata, rodbc

I am trying to connect R to Teradata and am not sure what the input items are to the `RODBC::odbcDriverConnect()`. There is a teradataR package, but it is only used with R versions 3 and under, which I neither have nor want to switch to. Below is a list of the input parameters to get ODBCDriverConnect to work. "Connection" I believe is most important. I need to get an address for a driver that I don't even know if I have. This is what I need most help with. How do I get a driver for Teradata to connect to R? IT at my work is not sure how to do this. Also, if anyone knows of another way to connect Teradata to R (some other package?), please let me know.

```
connection = ""
case
 believeNRows = TRUE
 colQuote, tabQuote = colQuote
interpretDot = TRUE
 DBMSencoding = "",
rows_at_time = 100
 readOnlyOptimize = FALSE
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to connect R to Teradata using RODBC package. Here is how to do it if you are working on a pc and have a Teradata driver.

**Set up DSN:**

1. Go to:  control panel-> administrative tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) -> User DSN tab -> click add-> select Teradata driver (or whatever driver you will be using. ie. could be sql) and press finish.
2. A box will pop up that needs to be filled in. The following fields need to be filled:

   **Name:** Can be any name you would like. I chose TeraDataRConnection, for example. 
   **Name or IP address (DBC name or address):**  Mine for example is: Databasename.companyname.com.  I looked to see how Microsoft access was connected to the database and in doing that, found  the DBC address. 
   **Username:** username that you use to connect to database.
   **Password:** password use to connect to databases (if you don't put your password in here, you will have to manually type it into R every time you connect.

**In R:**

Download RODBC package

```
library(RODBC)

ch=odbcConnect("TeraDataRConnection",  uid="USERNAME HERE",pwd="PASSWORD HERE")
```

If you want to confim you are connected, you can type in this code to see the tables:

```
ListOfTables=sqlTables(ch,tableType="TABLE")
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to connect to Teradata and created a Shiny app which reads data from it.
Firstly we need to install `RODBC` package in our R. Prerequisite of it is  R (≥ 4.0.0) version. No admin access is required to upgrade R even in enterprise laptops.

Follow below steps to successfully setup connection.

1. Create ODBC Data Sources to connect to Teradata. The connection should be either in 64bit or 32bit, depending on R software.
2. Use below code snippet to get the data into reactive variable

```
data <- reactive({
  ch <- odbcConnect(dsn = "DSNName", uid = "username", pwd = "password")
  sqlQuery(ch,paste('select * from emp ')
           })
```

*DSNName - Name of DSN connection created*

You can use `data()` to display and use the value stored in it.
Enjoy!